# Transforming TT files in MsBuild

Tags: msbuild, t4, dsl, dsl-tools

I need to build a DSL Solution using MsBuild and want to be able to transform the TT files, I have tried the guide on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423(VS.100).aspx but I am getting the following errors:

> Failed to resolve include text for file:{0}

and also

> Loading the include file '{0}'
>   returned a null or empty string.

There is a page on MSDN which has these issues and there resolutions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126242(VS.100).aspx but don't really give me enough information to resolve the issue.

One thing to note in the error it has the following path:

> Error 72  Failed to resolve include
>   text for
>   file:C:\source\XXXXXXXX\Dsl\GeneratedCode\Dsl\ToolboxHelper.tt.
>   Line=-1, Column=-1    Dsl

but the location of the actual TT file is

> C:\source\XXXXXXXX\Dsl\GeneratedCode\ToolboxHelper.tt

Comment: Cross-posted from MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/dslvsarchx/thread/088f07a5-bd4d-42cf-9918-b6b06ef6a0d7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered for me on MSDN:

[Transforming TT files in MsBuild](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/dslvsarchx/thread/088f07a5-bd4d-42cf-9918-b6b06ef6a0d7)

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was fixed by installing the "T4 Toolbox for Visual Studio 2015" extension. Apparently I only had the T4 editor installed.

Answer (score 0):

Historically the story between T4 and MSBuild has been bad. Now with VS 2010 they are introducing [Preprocessed templates](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/09/t4-preprocessed-text-templates/). If you are using VS 2010 you should take a look at using those.

Comment: Sayed, Preprocessed templates are indeed a great new feature in VS2010, but they're  orthogonal to MsBuild transformation - you can do msbuild of preprocessed or regular templates.